# Getting API error occurred: account_inactive when using Slack Postmessage api to send message to slack user

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am building a slack app that would send messages to user. Recently I am getting an error which says "**account_inactive**". The slack documentation describes the following error as below

```
Authentication token is for a deleted user or workspace when using a bot token.
```

I tried sending a message to a deactivated slack user using "chat.postMessage" using a bot token "xoxb-token" and the API returns success all the time. It would be great if anyone can help me with what causes this error.

PS: I am not using BoltJS, I am using he JS SDK directly.

Comment: I think the message is in regards to your app's authentication token, not the user you're trying to send to

Comment: @Phil By app's authentication token, do you mean signing secret and client secret? If yes, I checked the signing secret, client secret and client id, all the values seem to be correct.

Comment: He is talking about the "xoxb-token", you need to reinstall the app, it will let you know if there are any errors with the token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like your app has been uninstalled from the workspace. You can try calling [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) to see if the token is still valid.

Comment: This helps. I tried uninstalling the app and tried out auth.test api and got the same error. Is there any other scenario apart from the app being uninstalled, where I could get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this error recently.

In my case, the cause was that when a user account is deactivated, some apps they've installed are also deactivated. If this is the case for you, a member with the permission to manage apps will need to reactivate it.

More information can be found in [this Slack help article](https://slack.com/intl/en-au/help/articles/360000446446-Manage-deactivated-members-apps-and-integrations).